# UTL_FILE operations produces special characters in the output file

Tags: sql, database, oracle

We've some String values stored in Oracle DB. We're writing these values to a .DAT file . The query snippet in our package looks like below :

**Opening file :**

`l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(l_dir, l_file_name, 'W');`

**Writing to file :**

`UTL_FILE.putf(l_file, ('E' ||';'|| TO_CHAR(l_rownum) ||';'|| TO_CHAR(v_cdr_session_id_seq) ||';' || l_record_data));`

**String value in the DB :** `"Owner’s address"`

**String value in the .DAT file :** `"Ownerâ€™s address"`

**Question is :** How to avoid those special special characters while writing it to an output file?

Comment: Are you sure the file has that, and it's not just how you're viewing it? Looks like a character set mismatch though. What is the data type of l_record_data, what are your database and national character sets, and what is your NLS_LANG? (See the last paragraph [of the operational notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70899)).

Comment: Hi @Alex Poole l_record_data is of type `VARCHAR2(5000)`; `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `AL32UTF8`, `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is `AL16UTF16`, and `NLS_LANGUAGE` is `AMERICAN`

Comment: What byte value(s) does that character have? Looks like a simple apostrophe. Shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: No, it is a [Right Single Quotation Mark U+2019](https://codepoints.net/U+2019)

Comment: If we create that String value in the DB directly (edit the column) then output in the file is proper ! For testing purpose we copied the String from browser ( from the page where bug was raised !).It's not working in this case.  **Values in the DB :** `"Owner's address created in DB"`  and `"Owner’s address copied from browser"`  **Values in the output file :** `"Owner's address created in DB"` and `"Ownerâ€™s address copied from browser"`

Comment: @VGHegde - they are different characters, a simple single quote (apostrophe/tick) vs. a 'curly' quote - as Wernfried already pointed out. Look closely at how they are rendered in your previous comment. Or use `dump()` to see the actual character codepoints from bothstored values.

Comment: @Alex Poole Yes. They are different. In windows machine using Notepad ++ if we view the file, both the vlaues are proper. It's not showing proper values in linux machine ! Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: That could be your terminal software, your environment, or vi settings; or a combination. Start with - what is you $LANG set to? Make that something like `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` if it isn't already. And in vi/vim do `:set encoding` to see what that currently has.

Comment: `$LANG = en_US.UTF-8` and in vim `:set encoding = fileencoding=utf-8`

Comment: OK, then your terminal software is using Windows CP1252. What are you using to connect to the Linux box - PuTTY, an xterm, something else?

Comment: We are using Xshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising from comments, your Linux session and Vim configuration are both using UTF-8, but your terminal emulator software is using the [Windows-1252 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). That renders the 'curly' right-quote mark you have, `’`, which is [Unicode codepoint 2019](https://codepoints.net/U+2019), as `â€™`.

You need to change your emulator's configuration from Windows-1252 to UTF-8. Exactly how depends on which emulator you are using. For example, in PuTTY you can change the current session by right-clicking on the window title bar and choosing "Change settings...", then going to the "Window" category and its "Translation" subcategory, and changing the value from the default "Win 252 (Western)" to "UTF-8".

[image: PuTTY reconfiguration dialog]

If you have the file open in Vim you can control-L to redraw it. That will only affect the current session though; to make that change permanent you'll need to make the same change to the stored session settings, from the "New session..." dialog - loading your current settings, and remembering to save the changes before actually opening the new session.

Other emulators have similar settings but in different places. For XShell, [according to their web site](https://www.netsarang.com/products/xsh_key_features.html):

> You can easily switch to UTF8 encoding by selecting Unicode (UTF8) in the Encoding list on the Standard toolbar.

It looks like you can also set it for a session, [or as the default](https://www.netsarang.com/forum/xshell/2496/Allow_setting_global_default_charset).

Answer (score 2):

I assume your database uses character set `AL32UTF8` (which is the default nowadays). In such case try this:

```
l_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR(l_dir, l_file_name, 'W');

PUT_NCHAR(l_file, ('E;'|| l_rownum ||';'|| v_cdr_session_id_seq||';' ||l_record_data);
```

Note for function [FOPEN_NCHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70922): *Even though the contents of an NVARCHAR2 buffer may be AL16UTF16 or UTF8 (depending on the national character set of the database), the contents of the file are always read and written in UTF8.*

Comment: Hi @Wernfried Domscheit, I tried using `FOPEN_NCHAR` and `PUT_NCHAR`. It's not working. In Our `DB NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `AL32UTF8`, `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is `AL16UTF16`.

Comment: I think the output file is a proper UTF-8 File. However, your reader or text editor does not understand UTF-8 but considers this file being a [Windows CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoded file. Change the editor settings or convert the file after is has been created, e.g. http://www.webutils.pl/Charset-Converter

Comment: You are right. If we open the file using notepad++ it contains proper values ! We are viewing it in linux machine using vi command.